# How to load a Decision Tree Model without Spark or PMML in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I want to load a trained and saved `spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel`, and I want to load it in Java. I cannot use `spark.read().load(...)` because I am asked not to create `SparkSession`, and I cannot use`PMML` because it does not support `DecisionTree`. Could anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can you not create a SparkSession? Not even a local one? I guess you can use regular java serialization, but that's really not ideal.

Comment: PMML does support decision tree models. The model element is simply called `TreeModel` (not `DecisionTree`).